# Collected bitcoins at https://btcfree.win/ And made a GENERAL WITHDRAWAL 0.2 BTC

Tags: withdrawal

Collected bitcoins at https://btcfree.win/
And made a GENERAL WITHDRAWAL
0.2 BTC To the card, but unfortunately the withdrawal to the card did not arrive. Tell me how to find out if it will come at all or not???